# How to optimise a condition which checks for each object of an array of objects whether specific properties are not undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement, optimization

I want code optimisation for an `if`-statement because I otherwise have to add more key-value pairs into this condition with `&&`. I have an array of objects and the condition as with the following code example.

```js
let arr = [{
  a: 12,
  b: 14,
  c: undefined,
  d: undefined,
  e: 56,
  f: "file 1",
  g: "file 2",
  h: undefined,
}];

for (const item of arr) {
  if (
    item.a !== undefined &&
    item.b !== undefined &&
    item.c !== undefined &&
    item.d !== undefined &&
    item.e !== undefined &&
    item.f !== undefined &&
    item.g !== undefined
  ) {
    console.log("code works");
  } else {
    console.log("fails");
  }
}
```

I'm trying to optimise the above code, and I appreciative any suggestion.

Comment: Put the property names in an array and loop over the array rather than manually writing out each property reference.

Comment: why do yo have an array of one object?

Comment: Please try this & share your feedback: `console.log(arr.map(obj => Object.values(obj).some(v => v === undefined) ? 'fails' : 'code works').join(', '));`.

Comment: Did you miss `h` out on purpose?

Comment: "json object": there is no JSON in your question. You mean: JavaScript object.

Comment: I've to check undefined values for some keys not for all so that I've not return `h` key in if condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the Q. in a way that the OP does not want to check for every object's value being not the `undefined` value, and the OP rather wants to check whether some predefined properties (e.g. by a key list) need to be present and also not equal to `undefined`.

In this case one could implement a function which checks via a list of property names (key list) for each passed item/object whether such an object fulfills the above mentioned requirement.

Such a function could be passed as callback function to [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) in order to detect whether any of an array's item/object does fulfill the requirement.

```js
function isEveryPropertyFromBoundListDefined(item) {
  const keyList = this; // the bound list of defined keys.

  return keyList
    .every(key => item[key] !== undefined);
}

const sampleData_1 = [{
  a: 12, b: 14, c: undefined, d: undefined,
  e: 56, f: "file 1", g: "file 2", h: undefined,
}];
const sampleData_2 = [{
  e: 56, f: "file 1", g: "file 2", h: null,
}, {
  h: 1, g: 2, f: 3, e: 4,
}];
const listOfToBeDefinedKeys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];

console.log(
  sampleData_1
    // make use of `every`'s 2nd `thisArg` parameter.
    .every(isEveryPropertyFromBoundListDefined, listOfToBeDefinedKeys)
);
console.log(
  sampleData_2
    // make use of `every`'s 2nd `thisArg` parameter.
    .every(isEveryPropertyFromBoundListDefined, ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'])
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to write a shorter code. This is not a huge optimization

```js
let arr = [{
    a:12,
    b:14,
    c:undefined,
    d:undefined,
    e:56,
    f:"file 1",
    g:"file 2",
    h:undefined
}]
for(let key of arr){
if(Object.values(key).some((x) => x===undefined)){
console.log("fails")
}else{
console.log("code works")
}
}
```

Comment: my question is I've to check condition of `undefined` for particular key value not for all keys. so that I've not added `h` key in my if condition. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that accepts an object as an argument, gets its [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), and then use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if any of the values are `undefined`. `some` returns after finding the first match to the condition.

```js
const arr=[{a:12,b:14,c:undefined,d:undefined,e:56,f:'file 1',g:'file 2',h:undefined},{a:12,b:14,c:3,d:'bob from accounting',e:56,f:'file 1',g:'file 2',h:23},{a:12,b:14,c:3,d:'bob from accounting',e:56,f:'file 1',g:'file 2',h:undefined}];

function test(obj) {
  const values = Object.values(obj);
  return values.some(p => p === undefined);
}

const out = arr.map((obj, i) => {
  return `Code ${test(arr[i]) ? 'fails' : 'works'}`;
});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirement correctly, You have dynamic properties in an object and you want to check if all the properties in an object having values. If Yes,

Try this **:**

```js
let arr = [{
    a:12,
    b:14,
    c:undefined,
    d:undefined,
    e:56,
    f:"file 1",
    g:"file 2",
    h:undefined
}];

arr.forEach(obj => {
  let str = '';
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    str = obj[key] ? 'code works' : 'fails'
  })
  console.log(str);
});
```